# Paypal Sandbox account not logging

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

anybody Please guide me how I can login my sandbox account. I am trying to login from this url [developer paypal link](https://developer.paypal.com/) but unable to login. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the Sandbox. It appears that it is not working, I cannot create accounts etc.

Maybe someone can contact the techincal support of PayPal?